# Get all fields using Generics

Tags: java, generics

Task:
You need to get all fields of a specified class, including private and inluding fields from all superclasses.
Usuall approach is to get fields recusivly:

```
private static void getAllFieldsRecursive(List<Field> fields, Class<?> type) {
    fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(type.getDeclaredFields()));   
    if (type.getSuperclass() != null) {
        getAllFieldsRecursive(fields, type.getSuperclass());
    }
}
```

However the case doesn't cover overridden fields. 
Running code for:

```
class A {String myfield; String otherAField}
class B extends class A {String myField; String otherBField}
```

will give result: 
String B.myfield; String B.otherBField; String A.myfield, String A.otherField

Using Set will not help, because String A.myfield doesn't equal B.myfield

Solution below

Comment: "However the case doesn't cover overridden fields." There's no such thing as an overridden field. It's entirely correct to show four fields there. An instance of `B` *does* have four independent fields. It's also unclear what this has to do with generics...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, no it's not always correct to show all 4 fields. In some cases you need to know only the last version of the field with it's supported annotations, for example. And yes, fields are hidden, not overridden.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "last version". Your question states: "You need to get all fields of a specified class, including private and inluding fields from all superclasses." In the example you've given, there are four such fields. If you actually have a different task, you should state that in the question. It *is* always correct to show all 4 fields with the task described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Collect all fields declared, including superclasses.
 * @param type class
 * @return
 */
public static List<Field> getAllFields(Class<?> type) {
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    getAllFieldsRecursive(fields, type);
    return fields;
}

/**
 * Get fields recursively, starting from child.
 * Starting from child is important to support fields overriding.
 * @param fields all fields collected
 * @param type currently scanned class
 * Example:
 * class A {String myfield; String otherField}
 * class B extends class A {String myField; String bField}
 * Result: String B.myfield; String B.bField; String A.otherField
 */
private static void getAllFieldsRecursive(List<Field> fields, Class<?> type) {
    List<Field> declaredFields = Arrays.asList(type.getDeclaredFields()); //Start from child
    for (Field declaredField : declaredFields){
        if (!genericContainsField(declaredField, fields))
            fields.add(declaredField); //if field is not overridden in child, add it
    }
    if (type.getSuperclass() != null) {
        getAllFieldsRecursive(fields, type.getSuperclass());
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @param declaredField field we are comparing
 * @param fields current fields list
 * @return
 */
private static boolean genericContainsField(Field declaredField, List<Field> fields){
    for (Field field:fields){
        if (genericEqualsFields(field, declaredField))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Compares this {@code Field} against the specified object.  Returns
 * true if the objects are the same.  Two {@code Field} objects are the same if
 * they were have the same name and type.
 * Declared by the same class is NOT needed
 * Hack for Generic lookup, based on Field.equals()
 */
private static boolean genericEqualsFields(Field obj, Field other) {
    return (obj.getName() == other.getName())
            && (obj.getType() == other.getType());
}
```